# Application crashes with native code

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, crashlytics, .so

```
Crashed: .onlineradioapp|
0  gralloc.rk30board.so           0xb4a2d616 bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, true>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)
1  gralloc.rk30board.so           0xb4a315c9 (Missing)
2  gralloc.rk30board.so           0xb48e2465 art::JValue art::interpreter::ExecuteGotoImpl<true, false>(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue)
3  gralloc.rk30board.so           0xb4a1349d artInterpreterToInterpreterBridge
4  gralloc.rk30board.so           0xb4a2d031 bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)
5  gralloc.rk30board.so           0xb48f2fef art::JValue art::interpreter::ExecuteGotoImpl<false, false>(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue)
6  gralloc.rk30board.so           0xb4a133dd artInterpreterToInterpreterBridge
7  gralloc.rk30board.so           0xb4a2d031 bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)
8  gralloc.rk30board.so           0xb48f2c1b art::JValue art::interpreter::ExecuteGotoImpl<false, false>(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue)
9  gralloc.rk30board.so           0xb4a133dd artInterpreterToInterpreterBridge
10 gralloc.rk30board.so           0xb4a2d031 bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)
11 gralloc.rk30board.so           0xb4a30de9 (Missing)
12 gralloc.rk30board.so           0xb48f308b art::JValue art::interpreter::ExecuteGotoImpl<false, false>(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue)
13 gralloc.rk30board.so           0xb4a133dd artInterpreterToInterpreterBridge
14 gralloc.rk30board.so           0xb4a2d031 bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)
15 gralloc.rk30board.so           0xb48f2c1b art::JValue art::interpreter::ExecuteGotoImpl<false, false>(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue)
16 gralloc.rk30board.so           0xb4a133dd artInterpreterToInterpreterBridge
17 gralloc.rk30board.so           0xb4a2d031 bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)
18 gralloc.rk30board.so           0xb48f2c1b art::JValue art::interpreter::ExecuteGotoImpl<false, false>(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue)
19 gralloc.rk30board.so           0xb4a133dd artInterpreterToInterpreterBridge
20 gralloc.rk30board.so           0xb4a2d031 bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)
21 gralloc.rk30board.so           0xb48f2c1b art::JValue art::interpreter::ExecuteGotoImpl<false, false>(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue)
22 gralloc.rk30board.so           0xb4a133dd artInterpreterToInterpreterBridge
23 gralloc.rk30board.so           0xb4a2d031 bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)
24 gralloc.rk30board.so           0xb48f2c1b art::JValue art::interpreter::ExecuteGotoImpl<false, false>(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue)
25 gralloc.rk30board.so           0xb4a133dd artInterpreterToInterpreterBridge
26 gralloc.rk30board.so           0xb4a2d031 bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)
27 gralloc.rk30board.so           0xb48f2c1b art::JValue art::interpreter::ExecuteGotoImpl<false, false>(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue)
28 gralloc.rk30board.so           0xb4a133dd artInterpreterToInterpreterBridge
29 gralloc.rk30board.so           0xb4a2d031 bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)
30 gralloc.rk30board.so           0xb48f2c1b art::JValue art::interpreter::ExecuteGotoImpl<false, false>(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue)
31 gralloc.rk30board.so           0xb4a133dd artInterpreterToInterpreterBridge
32 gralloc.rk30board.so           0xb4a2d031 bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)
33 gralloc.rk30board.so           0xb4a30de9 (Missing)
34 gralloc.rk30board.so           0xb48f308b art::JValue art::interpreter::ExecuteGotoImpl<false, false>(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue)
35 gralloc.rk30board.so           0xb4a131b5 art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame*)
36 gralloc.rk30board.so           0xb4c1973b artQuickToInterpreterBridge
37 gralloc.rk30board.so           0xb491d003 (Missing)
38 boot.oat                       0x73b4e2bb (Missing)
```

I have seen many crash reports are reported on `Fabric` with above log, is there anyway to understand it and find the solution for it? I have tested on many devices but I am not able to produce above log. There are approx 300 crash reports on `Fabric console` within 7days. I have just enabled `CrashlyticsNdk()` in new update.
Can anyone help me to identify the issue.

Thank you.

Comment: Is this crash limited to specific devices?

Comment: mostly android version 5 and 6,you can check report from here http://crashes.to/s/09273513ec6

Comment: Looks like a ART related crash. This could be due to a custom ART implementation on certain phones. You could raise a bug on Android bug tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new

Comment: If you have device with crash then connect to machine via usb and dump archived crash (headstone) as ```adb logcat -s DEBUG```

Comment: @Ketan don't have device with crash,it's reported by clinet

Comment: This kind of crash appeared on our Crashlytics dashboard too for Android 6 devices only(until now). Did anyone reach a conclusion to what the cause might be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here I am answering my own question after long debugging, I have found a bug in my JNI code

**old code**

```
char signToken[endingNumber - startingNumber];
    int at = 0;
    for (int i = startingNumber; i < endingNumber; i++) {
        signToken[at] = cstr[i];
        at++;
    }
    signToken[at] = '\0';
```

**new code**

```
 char signToken[endingNumber - startingNumber + 1];
    int at = 0;
    for (int i = startingNumber; i < endingNumber; i++) {
        signToken[at] = cstr[i];
        at++;
    }
    signToken[at] = '\0';
```

it's simple login for a substring, where I have taken string size equal to a length of string but it's length of string+1 after updating size to N+1, I have resolved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have an older version or have issues in file gralloc.rk30board.so you need to update it.
try [This](https://github.com/Nu3001/device_rockchip_rk3188/blob/master/libs/osmem/gralloc.rk30board.so?raw=true) 
Hope this will help you. :)